# How to set relationships in symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new to both symfony2 and doctrine.In my project I have a table named clients,which stores clients details.clients table have a field named country id which is the primary key of country table.Can you please anybody tell me that,which relationship I have to set in this case.

Comment: Did you check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the "[Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)" part of the documentation

`Client`  > `Country` (ManyToOne)

`Country` > `Client`  (OneToMany) (if needed)

**Client Entity,**

```
class Client
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="clients")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $country;
}
```

**Country Entity,**

```
class Country
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="country")
     */
     protected $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```